# Creation operator for single harmonic oscillator in Fock Space

Tags: operator-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

Given the Fock space:
$$\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{h}):=\bigoplus_0^\infty\mathcal{h}^{n}\text{ with } \mathcal{h}^{n}:=\bigotimes_1^n \mathcal{h},\mathcal{h}^0:=\mathbb{C}$$

Define the creation and annihilation operators by:
$$a(f)\alpha_1\otimes\ldots\otimes\alpha_n=\sqrt{n}\langle f,\alpha_n\rangle\alpha_1\otimes\ldots\otimes\alpha_{n-1}\qquad\alpha_i\in\mathcal{h}$$
$$a(f)^*\alpha_1\otimes\ldots\otimes\alpha_n=\sqrt{n}\langle f,\alpha_n\rangle\alpha_1\otimes\ldots\otimes\alpha_{n}\otimes f\qquad\alpha_i\in\mathcal{h}$$

Given this definition of the Fock Space and $\alpha \in \mathcal{h}$ how do I apply this to the following situation: 
A spin is coupled to a ***single*** harmonic oscillator. My prof then told me that for this case we have $\mathcal{h}=\mathbb{C}$. Is my Fock Space then only given by the following? (As I only have **one** harmonic oscillator)
$$\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{h}):=\bigoplus_0^1\mathcal{h}^{n}$$ 
He also said that the creation and annhilation are then given by simply $a$ and not $a(1)$ for $1\in \mathbb(C)$. So how do these operators then act on an element of the Fock Space? 
I assume the following but not sure if this is correct:
$$ a[\alpha]=\sqrt{1}<1,\alpha>=\alpha$$ and
$$ a^*[\alpha]=\sqrt{1+1} 1\otimes \alpha=\sqrt{2}\alpha$$ as $1,\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. I can see that this cannot be correct as $a$ not equal to the identity operator but then how does it act?
It seems I am a bit confused on the Fock Space and how the operators act. Any help for clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, you should be aware that if you talk about spin you have to specify whether you consider fermions or bosons. This will alter the construction of the Fock space slightly. The Fock space is always given by $\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty h^{i}$ where $h^{i}$ has to be constructed differently for bosons and fermions. The Fock space is the "arena" of the grand canonical ensemble from statistical mechanics and hence we consider any particle number $N\in\mathbb{N}$ at once.

Comment: The second question is typical sloppy physicists notation. In fact, one often consider a special basis representation of the Fock space known as occupation number representation. Is this familiar to you?

Comment: Thank you julian. It is not specified if we are talking about fermions or bosons. But since in his notes he talks about Bosons mostly (as we will later get to Weyl Operator etc and these are only necessary for the Boson case) I assume Bosons.

Comment: Yes, that basis is familiar to me. But unfortunately we are not using this at all. And it doesn't seem necessary either. This I guess is more for my understanding in general.

Comment: The question goes back to this problem
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/357866/solvable-model-with-harmonic-oscillator

Comment: I forgot to tag you @julian

Comment: Are you sure that your single particle Hilbert space is given by $\mathbb{C}$? In particular, we would have $\mathbb{C}^{\otimes N}=\mathbb{C}$ for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Nevertheless, we can carry out the construction in this case, but then we cannot distinguished between the vaccum and the one particle state.